# Cocoa-Touch – Core Data updating many-to-many relationships

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, relationship

I have two entities, one called `Group` and the other called `Contact`. They have a many-to-many relationship (with a minimum of one). Thus, at least one contact can belong to one or many groups and at least one group can belong to one or many contacts.

```
Contact <<-->> Group
```

Now when I want to update a group I have in my view controller my subclassed NSManagedObject `Group` available. (`@property (nonatomic, strong) Group *selectedGroup;`)

Say if group at first has a relationship with 3 contacts, after I updated that group it should have 2 contacts (1 of the original contacts and 1 new contact).

```
Before update    After Update
Group            Group
-----            -----
ContactA         ContactA
ContactB         ContactD
ContactC
```

`ContactA` should stay intact.

This means that `ContactB` relationship should be removed from the Group (and also should be deleted from the Contact entity since no other group has a relationship with `ContactB`)

`ContactC` should be created.

How would I handle this scenario? I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you generate model classes for your core data models? If so you should have CoreDataGeneratedAccessors created that look like this in your Group class:

```
- (void)addContactObject:(Contact *)value;
- (void)removeContactObject:(Contact *)value;
```

You could then do the following:

```
Group *group = ...
Contact *contactB = ...
Contact *contactC = ...
Contact *contactD = ...
[group addContactObject:contactD];
[group removeContactObject:contactB];
[group removeContactObject:contactC];
//save your context
```

Comment: Yep, I've generated model classes. So I see your code is editing the specific group, but I don't see anything related to deleting `ContactB` completely from the Contact entity?

Comment: Given it's many to many I didn't know you wanted to entirely delete that Contact (given other groups may be related to it). Simply delete that object from the managedobjectcontext then.